# Using GDB with Eigen C++ library

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, eigen, eigen3

I am using the Eigen C++ library downloadable from http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/.
This is a C++ library for easier handling of Matrices and Arrays. I use g++ compiler and gdb for debugging. However, I found that I am unable to print the content of a Matrix (provided by Eigen) while using gdb.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to install a gdb extension that you can find in [eigen/debug/gdb/](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/debug/gdb/printers.py).

The comment at the beginning of the file explains how to install it.

Comment: Is there something similar for lldb on mac os x?

Comment: I'm not aware of lldb script yet, but it should be difficult to adapt the gdb one to lldb.

Comment: link in the answer is dead

Comment: Can you explain how to install this python file?

Comment: It's explained in the file itself!

Comment: I have installed it but it's unclear to me how to use it. Could you provide any info on that? I'm using the eclipse debugger btw

Answer (score 27):

One trick you can use is the .data() member, it gives you a pointer to the raw array that contains the data. With that you can print it in GDB like so:

```
print *X.data()@Length_X
```

where X is the eigen variable and Length_X is the product of its rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [github project](https://github.com/dmillard/eigengdb) specifically for adding eigen printing support to GDB.

It appears to be based on the code linked in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085465/using-gdb-with-eigen-c-library#answer-25088214).