# Debugging Eigen in VSCode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, eigen, vscode-debugger

During debugging I'd like to have access to eigen matrices and vectors values. It seems that once I have a `.natvis` file, a [custom view of c++ object could be created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019). There is a `.natvis` file for Eigen [here](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/tip/debug/msvc/eigen.natvis), however I don't know a way to integrate it with VSCode. I also tried a [gdb extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085465/using-gdb-with-eigen-c-library) but didn't work out.

[image: Current debugger view]

How can I do that? Or what other solution do I have?

Comment: @SumitDey I think I have done something wrong then! It is working now.

Comment: @SumitDey Would you mind writing a tutorial for that so I can mark your answer as right answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[GDB Extension](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/raw/default/debug/gdb/printers.py)**

It is basic but supports fixed size as well as dynamic size matrices, and should suffice for ordinary use cases.
Result: Expect to view Eigen matrices on VS Code as the [sample here](https://pasteboard.co/IIDQMsb.png).

---

**Setup** (linux)

1. Copy / create required files:

```
wget -P ~/gdbExtensions/ "https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/raw/default/debug/gdb/printers.py"
touch ~/gdbExtensions/__init__.py
```

2. Add extension to the `.gdbinit` (replace `<USER>` with username; basically provide absolute path to `~/gdbExtensions`):

```
echo -en "\
python \n\
import sys \n\
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/<USER>/gdbExtensions') \n\
from printers import register_eigen_printers \n\
register_eigen_printers (None) \n\
end\n" >> ~/.gdbinit
```

The above info is available in the [file documentation](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/raw/default/debug/gdb/printers.py).

Comment: Above links are no longer functioning. The gdb debug `printers.py` can be found here instead: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/tree/master/debug/gdb. See also the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085465/using-gdb-with-eigen-c-library.

Comment: When will the .gdbinit be executed? It seems that the .gdbinit file does not work.